# PySimpleGUI change cprint output destination with param:window

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Have 2 Multiline elements in my window, 1 has param: `reroute_cprint=True`. When  "Add" button is pressed I want to print to the 2:nd Multiline.

Want to change the output destination for `sg.cprint()` in its paramaters, something like this:

```
if event == -B_ADD-':
        sg.cprint("Text to print", window=window['-ML_QUE-'])
```

Now I have a "workaround"

```
if event == -B_ADD-':
        sg.cprint_set_output_destination(window, '-ML_QUE-')
        sg.cprint("Text to print")
        sg.cprint_set_output_destination(window, '-ML_MAIN-')
```

Tried different key's in cprint param but get 'AttributeError', ex.

mline = destination_window.find_element(destination_key, silent_on_error=True)  # type: Multiline
AttributeError: 'Multiline' object has no attribute 'find_element'

What would be the right param to use?

Answer (score 1):

the correct code should be

```
if event == -B_ADD-':
        sg.cprint("Text to print", key='-ML_QUE-')
```

Its the 'key' param that overrides the prev set cprint output destination, not the window param

Comment: Spent so long time and just after posting I toke one more look at the Demo code for cprint and one extra look in the doc string, it was all there, even tho not super clear to me, but Im a newbie and learning.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).